# java - NIO: read until buffer size or delimiter

Tags: java, sockets, nio, data-transfer

Let's say I hava client connected via a NIO `SocketChannel`, that will send requests of the form

```
<command>\r\n
```

which may or may not be followed by

```
<value>\r\n
```

depending on the command. If it is, `<command>` will include the size (in bytes) of the `<value>` sent afterwards.

Now I'm new to this NIO stuff, but obvoiusly, I need to read the `<command>` first to prepare a buffer to receive the `<value>`. How do I do that, though?

For `<command>` can be of varying length and although I do know the maximum length, I suspect that if I get it wrong (e.g. read maximum length when command is shorter) I will end up reading some of that `<value>` into the same buffer I used to receive the `<command>` in.

Is there a way to cut the read at `\r\n`?

(I should mention that I am not allowed to use any external libraries.)

**EDIT**

My latest try,

```
private void read(SelectionKey k) throws IOException{
    SocketChannel client = (SocketChannel)k.channel();
    buffer.clear();

    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.socket().getInputStream()));


    System.out.println(is.readLine());
}
```

results (somewhat unsurprisingly) in a `java.nio.channels.IllegalBlockingModeException`.

Comment: you don't need to cut it, just read until you fill your buffer. Then check if you have read the whole command, if not - increase the buffer and continue reading. When you've read the command you can "compact the buffer" - i.e remove all bytes that are part of teh command to free space for the `read`. and continue reading

Comment: @SvetlinZarev And how do you propose I check "if I have read the whole command"? Walk through the buffer and check if I've seen ``\r\n``?